# Prove limit property by induction

Tags: calculus, induction

Assume that if $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) = L$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}g(x) = K$, then

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f(x)+g(x)] = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) + \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}g(x) = L+K$

and

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f(x)g(x)] = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}g(x) = LK$

Prove, by induction, that if $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f_1(x) = L_1$,$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f_2(x) = L_2$,...,$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f_n(x) = L_n$, then, for all $n \ge 2$

$1.$ $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)+f_2(x)+...+f_n(x)] = L_1+L_2+...+L_n$

$2.$ $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)f_2(x)...f_n(x)] = L_1L_2...L_n$

Proof of $1$:

Base case $n=2$:

It follows from the property

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)+f_2(x)] = L_1+L_2$

Assume for $n=k$

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)+f_2(x)+...+f_k(x)] = L_1+L_2+...+L_k$

Case $n=k+1$

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)+f_2(x)+...+f_k(x)+f_{k+1}(x)] = \\\ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[(f_1(x)+f_2(x)+...+f_k(x))+f_{k+1}(x)] = \\\ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)+f_2(x)+...+f_k(x)]+\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f_{k+1}(x) = \\\ (L_1+L_2+...+L_k)+L_{k+1}$

Now the Proof of $2$:

Base case $n=2$:

It follows from the property

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)f_2(x)] = L_1L_2$

Assume for $n=k$

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)f_2(x)...f_k(x)] = L_1L_2...L_k$

Case $n=k+1$

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)f_2(x)...f_k(x)f_{k+1}(x)] = \\\ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[(f_1(x)f_2(x)...f_k(x))f_{k+1}(x)] = \\\ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}[f_1(x)f_2(x)...f_k(x)]\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f_{k+1}(x) = \\\ (L_1L_2...L_k)L_{k+1}$

I'm afraid it's not supposed to be this simple, or is it ?

Comment: Yeah, it's about that simple. Some instructors might want you to explicitly identify what you're using to justify each particular step, but that's being very strict. And if you're sort of new to induction it can be nice to point out exactly where you use the induction assumption. But by the time you get to grad school people won't even bother to write out these details; they'll just say "by induction".